# Need a generic term for desktop crafting assistance machines

Tags: discussion, tags

We've had a few questions on desktop cutting machines like the Cricut and Silhouette. The Silhouette question was tagged with Cameo4 (the model), and that tag apparently got deleted after six months as a single-use tag<sup>[1]</sup>.

The machines are on-topic, but we don't have a tag for them, other than the generic [cutting], which doesn't provide a clue that it's about a machine.  There's a special audience for these, and a tag is needed to attract the right readers and answerers.

We don't get enough questions for a model or branded machine tag (they would get deleted after six months).

Bigger picture, there are also other small machines used in a crafting workflow, like embossing machines.  What sets all of these machines apart is that they do a task that is also done manually, but doing it on the machine is associated with fundamentally different kinds of questions, and the audiences are different.

Ideally, we would use a tag for the type of machine, like [cutting-machine] or [embossing-machine], but we get few such questions at this stage.  For now, we could use a generic tag like [crafting-machine](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crafting-machine) as a meta tag, supplemented with a tag for the type of process.  That would serve the purpose of identifying that the question is about using a machine rather than doing it manually.  So, for example, a question tagged [cutting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cutting)+[crafting-machine](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crafting-machine) would hopefully register with Cricut users that it's a question relevant to them.

Can anyone think of a better generic term for "desktop crafting assistance machine" that would fit in a tag and be intuitive?

Alternatively, do you think the tag needs to be specific to the type of machine in order to serve the purpose?  So, for example, we could create something like a [cutting-machine](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cutting-machine) tag now to cover those kinds of machines, and create an [embossing-machine](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embossing-machine) tag when we get some questions on those.  That would be a bit more intuitive.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> It's still here as a stub because it's linked to a deleted synonym.

Comment: Just [machine] is too vague, you think? Of course, we can make smart use of tag synonyms here, and let [crafting-machine] and [embossing-machine] lead back to a broader tag like [crafting-machine] automatically. Tags for other such machines can be made synonymous in the future, or even separated if a sufficient amount of questions warrant a unique tag.

Comment: @Joachim, I hadn't thought of [machine], and that's a great solution for main page purposes. [cutting]+[machine] or [embossing]+[machine] covers manual plus machine by adding just one general-purpose meta tag. The only problem is that a Cricut user, for example, coming up with tags to apply probably wouldn't think of [machine]. If there was a [cutting-machine] tag, they might intuitively think of that, or starting to type "cutting" would display that choice. A [machine] tag is likely to be something someone would need to edit in after the fact. (cont'd)

Comment: Maybe a [machine] main tag with synonomized more specific tags would work. I'm not sure whether searches would handle that. Say both [cutting-machine] and [embossing-machine] were synonomized with [machine], which is what would show on the question. If someone searches on [embossing-machine], what questions show up? (just Qs originally tagged as such? all Qs the system synonomized with [machine]?) Since synonomizing means they're all the same, I'm thinking the system would show everything. Of course for the near future, that might mean one extra Q.

Comment: If we have both specific tags, anyway, do we gain anything by synonomizing them with a more general tag?

Comment: I'm afraid just [machine] is too broad to be a useful tag, because there are also knitting machines and sewing machines (that have a tag [sewing-machine]) and the audience for them is different than the audience for cutting machines. OTOH [cutting-machine] would also include laser cutters or plotters, which are programmed and used in similar ways and probably have similar problems. I think [sewing-machine], [cutting-machine], [embossing-machine] and [knitting-machine] would be the most practical tags, but currently we have 0 questions about knitting machines.

Comment: Oh, and *technically* an embroidery machine is different from a sewing machine and creates different questions, but until now users mostly tagged [sewing-machine] + [embroidery].

Comment: @Elmy, couldn't find a facepalm emoji. I was concentrating on gadgets, and forgot all about sewing machines, which is a nice precedent. I didn't spot any knitting machine questions yet in a quick skim. Is it worth changing the workaround for embroidery machines with a dedicated tag or just leave that as-is, at least for now? You're batting a thousand on these questions.

Comment: @fixer1234 Honestly, I'm not sure about separating [sewing-machine] and [embroidery-machine]. Some problems like thread tension are the same, but other problems like programming a pattern are completely different. But there's also the grey area of people using a regular sewing machine for free hand embroidery.

Comment: @Elmy, I took a shot at the wiki for the [cutting-machine] tag. We don't normally include a big meta discussion, but it seemed like computer-controlled machines are a grey area and it wouldn't hurt. Please take a look when you get a chance and see if what I wrote matches your thoughts (or even whether we shouldn't nail it down in that detail). Tnx

Comment: @Joachim, ^ ^ ^. https://crafts.stackexchange.com/tags/cutting-machine/info

Comment: @fixer1234 looks ok to me

Comment: I think a wiki like that should focus on its use and be to-the-point, and I fear most users won't read through the entire text. I think a concise description of what is off-topic is fine, but dedicating half of the tag wiki to what it is not about is overkill IMHO, and I think more suitable for a Meta thread (maybe a broad question where all answers are dedicated to a single tag?).